# Unable to run react-native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

The following command is not working. Please help.

**react-native run-android**

Added `jre 1.8` path in Environment variables. Still getting below error

[image: react-native run-android not working]

Comment: Same is resolved.Thank you ... Changed JDK path in Android studio .

Answer (score 0):

Check you have created or copied the "local.properties" file in the android folder which content has your Android SDK path

sdk.dir=/home/user/Android/Sdk

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1. Check JDK and SDK configuration (if anything you missed)
2. Check the Android SDK path like below :

Go to your React native Project -> Android
Create a file local.properties ( path is : yourproject/android/local.properties)
Open the file
paste your Android SDK path like below

```
in Windows sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
in macOS sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
in linux sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
```

Now, Run the `react-native run-android` in your terminal.

Comment: then check step 2.